# Flutter: GraphQLError: invalid input syntax for type uuid: ""

Tags: firebase, flutter, graphql, hasura

I am new to GraphQL and Hasura. I am acquiring a firebase user JWT and passing it to a Hasura GraphQL endpoint, but I'm receiving error messages

```
GTMSessionFetcher invoking fetch callbacks, data {length = 3322, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 22616363 6573735f 746f6b65 ... 31303535 220a7d0a }, error (null)


 flutter: OperationException(linkException: null, graphqlErrors: [GraphQLError(message: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "", locations: null, path: null, extensions: {path: $.selectionSet.insert_member_one.args.object, code: data-exception})])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the `URL` passed in the initialization of `graphql client` is wrong or has special characters included. Try using

```
Uri.Parse('YOUR_URL_HERE)
```

in the GraphQLClient()

Answer (score 0):

An empty string is 1: not null, if it's a nullable field, and 2: not a valid uuid (v4 at least, I ran into this same problem) use `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` as nil/empty uuid v4.

https://www.uuidgenerator.net/version-nil